# JVM terminated. Exit code=1

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am trying to run eclipse on Linux. But I am getting message JVM terminated. Exit code = 1 as soon as I try to open eclipse.
How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: which linux distribution are you using?

Comment: it is REHL-based

Comment: pls post the entire error log